# Scrollview won't scroll even when keypad appears

Tags: java, android, xml

When the keypad appears when the user clicks on an EditText, parts of the layout is covered by the keypad. So I tried using ScrollView so the user can scroll down and see the rest of the layout. But its not scrolling. I can't seem to get my scroll view working. The I have searched on stackoverflow for the solution for 3 hours and couldn't find it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/new_meal_form_relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/meal_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text="@string/meal_label"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/meal_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/meal_label"
            android:hint="Event Title"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/meal_location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/meal_name"
            android:hint="Location(eg: CSC Room232)* "
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/meal_event"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/meal_location"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Description of the event. What kind of food. Any additional info... \n"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/meal_event"
            android:text="Rating: "/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/rating_spinner"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewRequired"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewRating"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRequired"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewRating"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="*Required"

            android:textColor="#ffff4b48"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <com.parse.ParseImageView
            android:id="@+id/meal_preview_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rating_spinner"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/photo_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_photo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/meal_preview_image"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photo_button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:background="#ffff001f"
            android:text="@string/post_button_text"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:layout_below="@+id/photo_button"
            android:text="@string/cancel_button_text"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="20px"
            android:layout_height="20px"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rating_spinner"
            android:id="@+id/space"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have also tried adding "adjustResize" to the manifest file but it didn't do anything.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: android:fillViewport="true" this line has caused me some problems where my scroll view would stop scrolling after adding it. try removing it and see if your scrollview will scroll

Comment: two things to do
1) remove property android:fillViewport="true"
2) change scroll view  layout height wrap_content

Comment: I did both of that and its still not working. Keyboard still covers up the Post button after image is taken and image preview shows up in the layout. And still can't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ScrollView` layout height should be `wrap_content`. Right now it's `match_parent` which means be as tall as my parent, not; be as tall as the content within me.

Comment: I tried it but it still wouldn't work. The keyboard still covers the Post button after the photo is taken and image preview shows up. And I still can't scroll.